# My cookies automatically expire after 30 minutes

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I am using `cookie-parser` for express but I am confused by the way my cookies behave :

I set my cookie to expires after 1 hour but it expires always after 30 minutes

```
res.cookie('mycookie', 'value',{expire: Date.now() + 3600000,secure:true,httpOnly:true});
```

I also tried

```
res.cookie('mycookie','value',{maxAge:3600000,secure:true,httpOnly:true});
```

whithout success. My cookie always expires after 30 minutes, even when I set 5 minutes , it expires 30 minutes later. I really can't figure out what's wrong.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a number as `Date.now() + 3600000`
But according to [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.cookie); you need to pass `Date` like `new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)`.

```
res.cookie('rememberme', '1', { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), httpOnly: true })
```